# How can I restrict phpmyadmin on AWS EC2 instance apache webserver by IP address?

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I am recently wanted to restrict my phpmyadmin by IP address. I am using AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and web server is Apache2. My database is AWS RDS mysql. I am also using a AWS Load Balancer. My EC2 instance is under the AWS ELB.
I already tried in phymyadmin config file by adding bellow lines

```
vim /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from X.X.X.X
```

Here, X.X.X.X is my IP address. But unfortunately when I enter these lines, I don't get access to my www.{webserver}/phpmyadmin anymore from any host/PC. Not even from the host of that IP (X.X.X.X) address. I get 443 error on my browsers.
Any solution ?

Comment: What do your security groups look like? Why not just restrict access via security and nacl's?

Comment: I enable the port on the security group list !!

Comment: And that worked?

Comment: @strongjz No.
But I found something interesting. The rule worked. After implementing those lines, I can't access https://{web_address}/phpmyadmin from the allow IP host as well as from other machines.
But I can access https://{web_instace-IP_address}/phpmyadmin from the allow IP host but not from the other machines.
I think it is behaving like this because of AWS load balancer.